# Sidemenu Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-8.1, draggable

I've implented a working flyout-sidemenu like in the android musicplayer in windowsphone 8.
For that I used the Library Interactivity to get drag and drop functionality.

Now it seems that I can't use the functionality in windowsphone 8.1 anymore. The automatic conversion tool from microsoft I can't use. Our project is made for multiple platforms and has portable class library. We had to kick out the Silverlight-Part and thats why it is not convertible.

I searched the web for alternativs like doing it with gesturerecognizers but had no luck.

Maybe some of you has an idea?

Thx a lot for any reply.

Here the part with the old library:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <el:MouseDragElementBehavior  ConstrainToParentBounds="True" 
                                              Dragging="MouseDragRight_Dragging" 
                                              DragFinished="MouseDragRight_DragFinished" 
                                              DragBegun="MouseDrag_DragBegan"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chubosaurus Software, I figured it out:

1: Create an instance of `GestureRecognizer` with the settings you need

```
GestureRecognizer _gestureRecognizer = new GestureRecognizer();
_gestureRecognizer.GestureSettings =  GestureSettings.CrossSlide ;
```

2: Hook up the events that you need

```
_gestureRecognizer.CrossSliding += _gestureRecognizer_CrossSliding;
```

3: Depending on what gesture you need, you have to route the events to the recognizer. In this case it's

```
private void MainViewGrid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _gestureRecognizer.ProcessMoveEvents(e.GetIntermediatePoints(MainViewGrid));
}

private void MainViewGrid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _gestureRecognizer.ProcessDownEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(MainViewGrid));
}

private void MainViewGrid_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   _gestureRecognizer.ProcessUpEvent(e.GetCurrentPoint(MainViewGrid));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `GestureRecognizer`.  [MSDN: GestureRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx)

The GestureRecognizer class has these events.

CrossSliding

> Occurs when a user performs a slide or swipe gesture (through a single touch contact) within a content area that supports panning along a single axis only. The gesture must occur in a direction that is perpendicular to this panning axis.

Dragging

> Occurs when a user performs a slide or swipe gesture with a mouse or pen/stylus (single contact). 
>   Holding  Occurs when a user performs a press and hold gesture (with a single touch, mouse, or pen/stylus contact).

ManipulationCompleted

> Occurs when the input points are lifted and all subsequent motion (translation, expansion, or rotation) through inertia has ended.

ManipulationInertiaStarting

> Occurs when all contact points are lifted during a manipulation and the velocity of the manipulation is significant enough to initiate inertia behavior (translation, expansion, or rotation continue after the input pointers are lifted).

ManipulationStarted

> Occurs when one or more input points have been initiated and subsequent motion (translation, expansion, or rotation) has begun.

ManipulationUpdated

> Occurs after one or more input points have been initiated and subsequent motion (translation, expansion, or rotation) is under way.

RightTapped

> Occurs when the pointer input is interpreted as a right-tap gesture, regardless of input device. 
>   Tapped  Occurs when the pointer input is interpreted as a tap gesture.